# Text transparency Allegro 5

Tags: c++, c, opacity, allegro

Been using al_draw_textf for drawing text to screen and it works perfect.. except text transparency. Wondering if anyone knows how to make al_draw_textf or another allegro function/(or maybe shaders) display text with functionality to fade opacity. Appreciate it

Comment: You could try drawing the text to another bitmap and then drawing that bitmap with the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `al_map_rgba()` to set transparency with `al_draw_textf`
For example, `al_draw_textf(font, al_map_rgba(0,0,0,100),0,0,0,"Transparent");` will draw the the text black, but semi transparent. The last argument in `al_map_rgba()` is the alpha channel, which controls transparency (255 being opaque, 0 being transparent).